# Not sure how to create large arrays without OutOfMemory Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to create 2 large arrays of about 235000 strings each, reading from a text file, however I get an OutOfMemory error. Here is my code...

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
                getResources().getIdentifier("mobypos", "raw", getPackageName()));
        scanner = new Scanner(ins);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                String[] array;
                ALLWORDS = new String[233804];
                ALLPOS = new String[233804];
                while (i < 233804) {
                    array = scanner.nextLine().toString().split("\\\\");
                    ALLWORDS[i] = array[0];
                    ALLPOS[i] = array[1];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
```

When I try to run this, I receive this error,

```
11-01 15:15:54.026    6229-6229/dmj_tech.essayassist E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1913508 byte allocation with 574084 free bytes and 560KB until OOM"
11-01 15:15:54.027    6229-6229/dmj_tech.essayassist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

I understand, that it's running out of memory because it's a large task, but my question is how do complete this operation in a way that wont make my app crash? Its ok if the operation takes a while, speed isn't a priority as of now. 
Even if this process uses basically all of my memory for a while, doesn't it free back up once it stops this task? (Is there a way to do this, part by part, until its done?) I have seen a few posts about using cache, or internal directories temporarily, not sure if that would apply to this or not. I have little experience with android and any information would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with those values? Your example code just loads them. Also, you're using `Runnable` wrong.

Comment: Can you change the logic so it doesn't need all of the Strings in memory at the same time?

Comment: Agreed. Loading 467,608 strings is unlikely to work, particularly on low-end Android devices.

Comment: I need to access them for a short period of time, however they wouldn't have to be created at the same time. Is there any other way i access that amount of Strings, like from an SQL Database?

Comment: I dont think it is even an Android question. It really depends on what you want to do with those bulks of strings. So it comes to making a proper algorithm to solve your problem (which is not described in the question)

Comment: @Kayaman, I need to take a sentence from the user, and then search each word individually for its Part-Of-Speech, is there any use in using Runnable, at all in this instance? If I find out how to use it correctly

Comment: @Michael Liberman All i need from them is to search for the index of a word, in the "ALLWORDS", and use that index in the "ALLPOS" to find its POS, I would only need these arrays for a short time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. The minimum you can do is drop the strings to a db and query it without loading the strings into memory.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot